# Proof that there will always be data within 1 SD

Tags: analysis, statistics, standard-deviation

So we just started stats at school, and our teacher told us that no matter the data, no matter how distorted or weird it is, there will always be data within 1 standard deviation of the mean. Is this true?? Any way to prove this?

Comment: Well, the statement is slightly off but I expect your teacher is referring to [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)

Answer (score 0):

The "most extreme" distributions would be ones containing $2N$ data points , half of which have a value of $a$ and the other half a value of $b$

The mean of such a distribution is $\mu = \frac12(a+b)$

the standard deviation is $\sigma = \frac12 |b-a|$

So for this distribution every point is exactly one standard deviation from the mean